# Under what condition can a space be a dual space of some space $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We know that $c_0$ cannot be a dual space of any space $X$. So my question is: Is there any condition that we can know a space can be a dual space of some space $X$?

Comment: You can check whether the space given has extreme point or not. This statement follows from Krein-Milman Theorem and Banach-Alaoglu Theorem.

Comment: you mean the *unit ball of the space*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to the statement that the unit ball of $X$ is compact in some locally convex topology $\tau$ coarser than the original topology of $X$. Then you can equip $X$ with the finest topology that agrees with $\tau$ on bounded subsets and call $X_{\ast}$ the space of linear functionals continuous with respect to this topology. It holds that $(X_{\ast})^{\ast}=X$. On the other hand, if $X=Y^{\ast}$, then the unit ball is compact in the weak*-topology by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

Comment: The relevant paper is: http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11054/9075